# What regex engine does NextGen Mirth Connect use?

Tags: regex, alert, mirth

I'm setting up alerts in my Mirth Connect healthcare data processing system and want to filter for certain error messages to actually notify on. [NextGen's docs describe this helpful functionality](https://docs.nextgen.com/bundle/Mirth_User_Guide_4_4_0/page/connect/connect/topics/c_Alert_Error_Types_and_Regex_connect_ug.html) which is accessed via regex, but I cannot seem to find reference on the engine they use for it

Other paradigms like Python or Rhino EcmaScript/JavaScript outline this clearly. I imagine Mirth's regex functions nearly identically to other implementations' and that general tools like https://regexr.com/ would still help lots, but it's important to iron out these details to ensure the system is robust

Thank you!

Comment: That article you linked to has [this image](https://docs-be.nextgen.com/bundle/Mirth_User_Guide_4_4_0/page/connect/connect/graphics/image2017-6-10_11-35-10.png?_LANG=enus), which clearly says that the regex is supposed to be a "*Java-style*" one.

Comment: Since Mirth is implemented in Java, this tracks. Thank you

Comment: You might want to [post an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so that others having the same question will have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Per [this image in NextGen's article](https://docs-be.nextgen.com/bundle/Mirth_User_Guide_4_4_0/page/connect/connect/graphics/image2017-6-10_11-35-10.png?_LANG=enus),  the regex is supposed to be "Java-style"